# Lightning Headphones with a splitter?

Tags: iphone, lightning

I got these great-sounding new [Fidelio M2L/27 Lightning Headphones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00V4X6QGY) that take the digital signal through the lightning connector and then use the high-quality DAC in the headphones themselves so I can listen hi-fi audio from my iPhone 8. However, I am also a mobile app developer and hence I need to also often connect my phone to my computer to debug. I bought a [cheap lightning splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07BHM1FJG) (1 male lightning to 2 female lightning) on Amazon and it doesn't work with the earphones - even if that's the only thing plugged in.

1) Is this an issue with the splitter not being MFI certified? Will my headphones not work if they are the only things plugged in?

2) If I do get an MFi certified adapter will I be able to use the headphones and have the data connection to the computer at the same time? Do lightning connectors allow two data connections at once?

Comment: > "it does seem to work" 
did you mean "does not"?

Comment: It might be helpful to share what adapter you are using. Simply saying a "cheap one from Amazon" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Ok, @RushilSrivastava I added a link to the one I bought.

Comment: It claims only 'one headphone, one charger' nothing more. I'd guess there's no data on the 2nd port. Did you try both ports for the headset? Did you try the regular Apple headset?

Comment: The regular Apple headset did work but that's because its actually receiving an analog signal through the lightning cable. These earphones receive a digital signal that the earphones themselves then convert. But that is the essence of my question: are there lightning splitters that you can buy that allow data transfer to both plugs or is it always only audio in one and charge in the other?

Comment: @Rozgonyi You're incorrect about how the Apple headset works. The lightning cable does not feature an analog audio signal at all. The Apple headset uses the digital signal, just like your Fidelio headphones. There's a DAC built-in to the Apple headset.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up a couple of splitters including one from [Belkin](https://www.jbhifi.com.au/belkin/belkin-lightning-audio-charge-rockstar-charger/356135/) and another cheap one from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07CGLC7LJ). Neither splitter supports data transfer at all, through either port.

I'd hazard a guess that this isn't possible. At least I haven't been able to find a device that explicitly states that it does support data.